# Trying to acces a StackPanel inside of a DataGrid Cell

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, stackpanel

Right now I got stuck on trying to access a `StackPanel` inside of a `DataGrid` `Cell`.

My aim is to programmatically generate small pictures (badges) inside of a `StackPanel` based on another field inside a `DataGrid`.

This my XAML for the `Column`...

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" x:Name="generatedBandges">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <!--<Image Source="..\..\Image\badge.png" />-->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I just don't know how to get there, to generate badges for each `Row`...

1st edit:
I've tried to work around this by implementing repeated image and binding a width, but I cant get it to work and it only solves the problem if you have a single line of images(I need more lines :( )

Code Ive tried...

```
                  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Rectangle Height="15" Width="{Binding Badge}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\..\Image\sim.png" TileMode="Tile" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0,0,15,15"/>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Is there a way to bind the stackpanel? So I can add controls to it or something like that?

2nd edit:
So Ive tried this...but again cant get it working - could use a help..

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="..\..\Image\sim.png"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: you cannot access controls inside DataTemplate from code directly. Your best bet will be to bind the Image source to a property and change it as required. You may want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` also. Have a look at `BitmapSource` and `IValueConverter` too.

Comment: Well I'd like to duplicate the image several times acording the data in datagrid like with a movie ratings...some records having three stars and some five.

Comment: @DavidWaldo: What `StackPanel` of which row in the `DataGrid` are you trying to access and why?

Comment: It may seem dumb, but try using x:Bind instead of Binding for your ItemsSource